# jq - Use argument to construct a selector

Tags: bash, jq

I'm wondering if possible to use an argument to construct a field name in `jq`.

Example:

```
jq -rc \
   --arg secret_name ${secret_name} \
   --arg secret_value ${secret_value} \
   '.data.$secret_name = "$secret_value"'
```

In above example, I want to use value of argument `secret_name` to create a key under `.data`. Is this possible using `jq`?

Example Data:

```
secret_name=abc  
secret_value=xyz
```

JSON on which `jq` is run:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {},
    "kind": "Secret",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "kv-secrets",
        "namespace": "default"
    },
    "type": "Opaque"
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
      "abc": "xyz"
    },
    "kind": "Secret",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "secrets"
    },
    "type": "Opaque"
}
```

Do mind that I intend to run the original command to fill `.data` will more key-value pairs.

Comment: what should be the final result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a variable, you need to use the long `[...]` form for the key. You don't need to quote the variables in a JSON filter; the variable *is* the string value.

```
jq -rc \
   --arg secret_name "${secret_name}" \
   --arg secret_value "${secret_value}" \
   '.data[$secret_name] = $secret_value'
```

Comment: Since the key(s) may contain whitespace, I think it's worth noting that double quotes are recommended around the shell variable(s) to avoid a compiler error.

Comment: This fails, any idea why?
```C=$(cat test.json | jq -rc \
--arg env "${ENV}" \
--arg app "${APP}" \
'.[$env] .apps .[$app] .cloudfront_id')```

Comment: That's not a valid filter.  Do you want an array consisting of those four values, or a single string, or do you want, e.g., to pipe the output of `.[$env]` to `.apps`? (Don't reply to this comment; if you have  a problem, post a new question.)